# Sharing a picture on facebook with AddThis.shareItem using android

Tags: android, facebook, buffer, share, addthis

I'm trying to share a picture using AddThis.shareItem(this,"facebook",mShareTitle,mShareDescription,myBitmap); but I'm constantly receiving the 1MB buffer error "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION!!!" or Facebook "error try it later."

Does someone knows some way to avoid this? (maybe cleaning the buffer before sharing bitmap?).

All the code works fine, except the AddThis.shareItem(this,"facebook",mShareTitle,mShareDescription,myBitmap); part.

Thanks!

```
String imageURL= " "; //contains the path of the image on device
File imgFile = new  File(imageURL);


if(imgFile.exists()){
            Log.d(TAG, "imgFile.getAbsolutePath() " + imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());try {

                    //This is what I found in http://support.addthis.com/ and works everywhere except on facebook
                    AddThis.shareItem(this, "facebook",mShareTitle,mShareDescription,myBitmap);                 
                    //Sharing from web works fine
                    AddThis.shareItem(this, "facebook", "http://example.jpg" , mShareTitle, mShareDescription);
                    //I've tried this but it's not working 
                    AddThis.shareItem(this, "facebook", "imgFile.getAbsolutePath()", mShareTitle, mShareDescription);
                    //I've read something about avoid buffer using Uris, but I'm not doing it appropiately
                    AddThis.shareItem(this, "facebook", "Uri.fromFile(imgFile).getPath()", mShareTitle, mShareDescription);
                    //I've read something about avoid buffer using Uris, but I'm not doing it appropiately
                    AddThis.shareItem(this, "facebook", imageURL, mShareTitle, mShareDescription);
                    //Last try that doesn't work
                    String foo = "file://";
                    foo = foo.concat(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.d(TAG,"foo: "+foo);
                    Log.d(TAG,"imageURL: "+imageURL);
                    AddThis.shareItem(this, "facebook", "foo", mShareTitle, mShareDescription);                 

                } catch (ATDatabaseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, "ATDatabaseException: " + e);
                } catch (ATSharerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, "ATSharerException: " + e);

                }

            }
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "Image not found");

        }
```

Comment: What is AddThis? Does it add everything to a Bundle? In Android, you cannot pass a Bundle around that's over 1 MB (it gives you the FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error), so if your bitmap is over 1 MB, that's likely the issue.

Comment: Yes Ming Li I'm getting Binder transaction buffer error but I don't know how to solve it. 

AddThis is it: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381211-what-is-addthis-#.UftsrmROqCY 

but I don't really know how it behaves because  the line:

AddThis.shareItem(this,"facebook",mShareTitle,mShareDescription,myBitmap); 

works fine for twitter, google and other services testing the same image.

Comment: Update: I tried this code with diferent devices and it works with LG and HTC but not with samsung ones.